# Xaml Parse Exception Button Rederer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a button renderer. I followed the custom renderer for an entry found here:

The solution is build using PLC.

Am I using the wrong assemblies?

More info on error:

Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException was thrown

Type local:MyButton not found in  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry/

and I get a xaml parse exception error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"
    x:Class="MyApp.LoginPage"
    BackgroundColor="White">
    <StackLayout>           
            <local:MyButton
                Text="Login"
                TextColor="Blue"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Android Renderer:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using DeliveryTracker;
using DeliveryTracker.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyButton), typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]

    namespace MyApp.Droid
    {
        class MyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
            {
                base.OnDraw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
```

In Forms:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyButton : Button
    {
        public MyButton()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what error you've seen. "A xaml parse exception" doesn't give us nearly enough information. What's the error message? Do it specify a particular location within your XAML?

Comment: enable XAML Compilation to get more info about the root cause: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

Comment: The error comes from the XAML preview. After running the app in the simulator I get no errors and it display the custom button renderer.

Comment: @MartDavious File a bug : http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Try removing the `";assembly=MyApp"` part in your namespace declarations, so just `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"`. Did you by any change rename your project or namespaces or something? Make sure your namespace in the XAML is the same as where your control is declared.

Comment: `XamlParseException` always have a message set, and more often than not a position. Please update your question

Comment: Is you problem fixed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

> xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"

Instead of

> xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"

? If it works, you have probably renamed your project or changed your namespace. It has already happened to me. Check your control's namespace and make sure it is the same as in your XAML.

Comment: This worked for me! But what does it mean to exclude the assembly part? Isn't it needed?

Comment: The assembly part is required if you have the same namespace in more than one assembly I suppose. Most of the time, this is not the case, this is why removing it have no effect (or solve your problem if you renamed your project or changed your namespace).

Comment: But shouldn't there be some other way to resolve this, given that the cause of this problem is that the project was renamed? Like changing something in some configuration file?